# convert jpg to ping with transparency on outside pixels only

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg, transparency

Hopefully someone can help with this.  I need to take a JPG image and convert it to a PNG with the white converted to transparent.  Here's the complicated bit though, the object in the image may have white pixels and I don't want them transparent, just the pixels on the outside of the subject.  I presume the best way to do this is by scanning the pixels top to bottom and inside that left to right and right to left stoping at a non white pixel.

I need this to be done server side with PHP.  I've got imagemagick but I don't think it can do this.

Any help from you folks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Imagemagick, you an flood fill the outside to replace the white with transparency. I am not an expert in PHP Imagick, but I think it has a flood fill command.

Comment: You can definitely scan the pixels of interest. Then set affected pixels to transparent and export. I'd sooner reach for gd than imagemagick though, if it's possible in gd, mostly because it's easier to install. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, you can use -floodfill or -draw to do a flood fill to replace the white with transparency. Here is an example doing it one way. Sorry, I am not an expert on PHP Imagick, but it does have a flood fill command.

Input:

[image]

```
convert logo_wizard.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" result.png
```

[image]

Download result.png to see the transparent regions.